# Run setInterval on first render gives maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: reactjs

In the code snippet below, I add a random number to an array every 3 seconds using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval). This goes well, until I try to **also** call the function on the **first render** (see the commented line). This gives me this error: `Maximum update depth exceeded.`

```js
const [listItems, setListItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    function extendTheList() {
      const randNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      setListItems([...listItems, randNr]);
    }

    // extendTheList();

    const int = setInterval(() => {
      extendTheList();
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(int);
  }, [listItems]);
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-shamir-ltkh6m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `setListItems` changes `listItems` which triggers `useEffect` which triggers `setListItems` which triggers `useEffect` which triggers `setListItems` which triggers `useEffect` which triggers `setListItems` which triggers `useEffect` which triggers `setListItems` which triggers `useEffect` which triggers `setListItems` which triggers `useEffect` which triggers `setListItems`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the dependency to avoid infinite loop

```
const [listItems, setListItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    function extendTheList() {
      const randNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      setListItems(listItems => [...listItems, randNr]);
    }

    extendTheList();

    const int = setInterval(() => {
      extendTheList();
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(int);
  }, []);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-stallman-e1m4wo

Comment: You beat me to it. Would recommend to not use `listItems ` as the name in the function call though.

Comment: @Disco why not? It's shadowing but it shouldn't have any negative consequences

Comment: It is just bad practice since it breaks the `no-shadow`rule https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow
It just opens up the can for buggs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have `listItems`  in the dependency array of useEffect which will retrigger the useEffect every time you change listItems.

If you want to use the old value of the state use the function version of setState

```js
const [listItems, setListItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  function extendTheList() {
    const randNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    setListItems((currentItems) => [...currentItems, randNr]);
  }

  // extendTheList();

  const int = setInterval(() => {
    extendTheList();
  }, 3000);
  return () => clearInterval(int);
}, [setListItems]);
```